# Number inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I have four numbers $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$. I know the following inequalities about them.

$$ 1.~~~ a \geq c $$
$$ 2. ~~~b \geq d $$
$$3.~~~ c \geq d $$

From 1 and 3, we can get $ a \geq c \geq d.$ With these facts in hand, what can we say about the inequalities between $a$ and $b$ and between $a$ and $c$? For example, can we say $ b \geq a$?

Do we need additional information?

Comment: Between $a$ and $c$? $a\ge c$.

Comment: No. $b\ge d$ and nothing more

Comment: You could always draw a "number line" picture for the inequalities to convince yourself.  You'll see that $ \ b \ $ can be made as large as you like without violating the stated conditions, so these inequalities tells us nothing about where $ \ b \ $ stands relative to $ \ a \ $ ( or relative to $ \ c \ $  for that matter) .

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough information to say anything about how $b$ relates to anything but $d$. You could have $b \geq a$, $a \geq b \geq c$, or even $c \geq b$, and 1 - 3 would still hold provided $b \geq d$.

Answer (score 2):

$a \ge c$
$c \ge d$
$b \ge d$

```
            d                 c                  a
 <----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------->

            |---------------------------------------------------->
             b could be anywhere here
```

Answer (score 1):

For a question like this one should try an example. For, say, $(a,b,c,d)=(5,2,4,1)$ we have all three inequalities, i.e., $a\ge c$, $b\ge d$ and $c\ge d$. Nevertheless we have $b<a$, which answers your first question. 
To see whether one needs more information, you could draw a diagram, with $a,b,c,d$ as vertices, joining two numbers by an edge if they are related by $\le$, and putting the bigger number above. Including transitivity in the diagram (which means that $x\ge y$ and $y\ge z$ imply $x\ge z$), you will
see from the diagram that there is no relation between $a$ and $b$.